# Cálculo del n-ésimo número armónico

Tags: java, matemáticas

Tengo una serie de fracciones: **`1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n`**

El programa pide primeramente el número ***`n`*** y a continuación debería sumar las fracciones correspondientes. Pero, *¿cómo sería el código en Java?*
Esto es lo que he podido hacer:

```
/* Una constante para que el divisor sea fijo y no se pueda cambiar */
private static final double DIVISOR = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean datoValido = false;

    while (!datoValido){
        System.out.println("Introduce el divisor máximo.");

        datoValido = teclado.hasNextInt();

        if(datoValido){
           int dividendoMax = teclado.nextInt();

           double i = 1;
           double fraccion = 0;
           double resultado = 0;


            while (i<=dividendoMax){
               fraccion = DIVISOR/i;
               resultado = resultado + fraccion;
               i++;
           }
            System.out.println(resultado);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Dato no válido.");
            teclado.nextLine();
        } // fin if datoValido

    } //fin while

}
```

No sé si se podría enfocar de otra manera más sencilla.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que podrias dividir 1/denominador para convertirlo a decimal y sumar estos decimales, luego debes de hacer un metodo que convierta decimales a fracciones, hay librerias que hacen eso como la commans math3.

Comment: No no quiero el código entero, solo quiero que me expliquéis como podría enfocarlo, perdón si me he expresado mal

Comment: Tu código parece ser una buena manera de encarar el problema que enunciaste, y @Andres Manzalini complemento tu solución con un enfoque recursivo. quizás si detallas mejor el problema, o lo que te parece que le falta a tu enfoque tendrías mejores respuestas

Comment: Tu codigo no se ve mal. Lo más objectable en mi opinión es la comparación `i<=dividendoMax` donde comparas `double`  con `int` (lo cual convertirá automáticamente todo a `double`), y es peligroso hacer comparaciones por igualdad de `double` (aunque en este caso probablmente ande bien, es mala práctica). Te recomiendo cambiar `i` a `int`

Comment: Tampoco queda claro si te piden que sumes e imprimas el resultado como número de punto flotante, o que devuelvas la fracción exacta.

Answer (score 20):

📖 De acuerdo con *Wikipedia*:

> En matemáticas, se define el *n*-ésimo **número armónico** como la suma de los recíprocos de los primeros *n* números naturales:
>
> [image: fórmula]

💻 He aquí una solución con Streams y Lambdas de Java 8:

✱ ***Fracción decimal***

```
/* 
 * Se obtiene n
 */
int n = sc.nextInt();

double result =
        /* 
         * Se genera un stream de enteros, desde 1 a n
         */ 
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
        /* 
         * Se obtiene el inverso de cada número, dividiendo 1.0 entre el 
         * número, desde 1.0/1 a 1.0/n
         */
        .mapToDouble(e -> 1.0 / e)
        /*
         * Se obtiene la suma de todos lo números calculados previamente
         */
        .sum();

System.out.println(result);
```

> <sub>Si *n* = **1**, el resultado es: **1.0**
>
>   Si *n* = **2**, el resultado es: **1.5**
>
>   Si *n* = **3**, el resultado es: **1.8333333333333333**
>
>   Si *n* = **4**, el resultado es: **2.0833333333333335**
>
>   Si *n* = **5**, el resultado es: **2.283333333333333**</sub>

✱ ***Fracción común***

```
/* 
 * Se obtiene n
 */
int n = sc.nextInt();

/*
 * Se obtiene el mínimo común múltiplo de todos los denominadores, 
 * de 1 a n
 */
int denominador = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).reduce(1, (a, b) -> mcm(a, b));

/*
 * Se divide el mínimo común múltiplo entre cada denominador y se suma
 */
int numerador = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + (denominador / b));

/*
 * Se obtiene la fracción con el numerador y denominador calculados
 * previamente
 */
String result = String.format("%d/%d", numerador, denominador);

System.out.println(result);
```

Donde el método ***`mcm`***:

```
/**
 * @return máximo común divisor de a y b
 */
private static int mcd(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : mcd(b, a % b);
}

/**
 * @return mínimo común múltiplo de a y b
 */
private static int mcm(int a, int b) {
    return (Math.abs(a) / mcd(a, b)) * Math.abs(b);
}
```

> <sub>Si *n* = **1**, el resultado es: **1/1**
>
>   Si *n* = **2**, el resultado es: **3/2**
>
>   Si *n* = **3**, el resultado es: **11/6**
>
>   Si *n* = **4**, el resultado es: **25/12**
>
>   Si *n* = **5**, el resultado es: **137/60**</sub>

---

📓 ***Referencias***

- Número armónico. (2014, 11 de agosto). [*Wikipedia, La enciclopedia libre.* Fecha de consulta: 16:01, abril 18, 2017](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=N%C3%BAmero_arm%C3%B3nico&oldid=76300453).
- Inverso multiplicativo. (2017, 13 de abril). [*Wikipedia, La enciclopedia libre.* Fecha de consulta: 15:38, abril 18, 2017](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Inverso_multiplicativo&oldid=98325423).
- Mínimo común múltiplo. (2017, 16 de abril). [*Wikipedia, La enciclopedia libre.* Fecha de consulta: 16:03, abril 20, 2017](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=M%C3%ADnimo_com%C3%BAn_m%C3%BAltiplo&oldid=98399528).
- Máximo común divisor. (2017, 16 de abril). [*Wikipedia, La enciclopedia libre.* Fecha de consulta: 16:04, abril 20, 2017](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=M%C3%A1ximo_com%C3%BAn_divisor&oldid=98403665).

Answer (score 6):

Dejo una alternativa, que intenta predecir el [número armónico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_arm%C3%B3nico) sin tener que estar sumando términos uno por uno.

En el artículo de Wikipedia que habla sobre el número armónico, aparece la siguiente imagen.

[image: Gráfica.]

> El número armónico [image: H_n,1] con [image: n=x] con su límite asintótico [image: y+log(x)] (gráfica azul).

Lo que importa de la imagen es que es casi equivalente al logaritmo de **x**. La diferencia entre el número armónico y el logaritmo de **x** cuando **x** es infinito (un número muy grande), es la [constante de Euler-Mascheroni](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constante_de_Euler-Mascheroni), es decir que la diferencia se va aproximando a ese número, que es un número aparentemente irracional, **0,577215664901532860606**... Haciendo algunas cuentas, preparé una fórmula que se aproxima bastante, y no es exacto, ya que desconozco el funcionamiento de la función *gamma (γ)*, pero el tiempo de cálculo es extremadamente bajo a diferencia de iterar con un `for`.

[image: Fórmula]

El código en *Java* sería el siguiente:

```
public double numero_armonico(double x)
{
    return Math.log(x) + 0.5772156649015329 + 1/(2*x) - 1/(12*Math.pow(x,2))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Considerando el ejemplo, tenes el patrón equivalente a la sumatoria de las 1/n fracciones.

El algoritmo se puede resolver de forma iterativa (tu resolucion) o de forma recursiva.

Pasándolo a código, quedaría algo así:

ITERATIVO

```
public double getFraccion(int n) {
double out=0;
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    out+= 1/i
return out;
}
```

RECURSIVO

```
public double getFraccion(int n) {
if (n==1)
    return 1;
else    
    return (getFraccion(n-1) + 1/n);
}
```